# Scala Type mismatch for Generic Class with bounds

Tags: scala, type-bounds

I've been trying out a few little things to try and understand Scala's Variance and Type Bounds syntax.

```
class Animal() {
  def says():String = "???"  
}
class Dog() extends Animal {
  override def says():String = "woof"
}

val adog = new Dog

class Zoo[A <: Animal](thing: A) {
  def whoami()=thing.getClass
  def chat()=thing.says
}
```

How ever, when I try to create an instance of the object I get:

```
scala> val cage = new Zoo[Dog](adog)
<console>:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : this.Dog
 required: this.Dog
       val cage = new Zoo[Dog](adog)
```

I don't quite understand what the compiler is telling me?

tks

Comment: What version of scala are you using? Your example works for me.

Comment: Using Scala version 2.9.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_40)

Comment: Executing above code in a Scala 2.9.3 REPL works for me. I guess you did execute some parts more than once, for example you re-executed the definition of class `Dog` after you created the `adog` instance, resulting in a mismatch between the two classes.

Comment: Yes, this [works](http://ideone.com/p0lMyn)

Comment: But, anyway, I recommend updating to latest stable Scala version, 2.9.x is outdated.

Comment: 2.9.3 is considered current. 2.10 is clearly advised for new projects, modulo required but as-yet unavailable 3rd-party Scala libraries...

Comment: The above error I got is obtain from a fresh REPL. Nothing else is executed on the console. Unfortunately I am not able to upgrade to 2.9.10 since what I'm really using is Spark (http://spark.incubator.apache.org/) which currently only works with Scala 2.9.3...

Comment: I just ran the code on an unadulterated Scala REPL.. and it worked... it must be something that Spark has introduced. I'll ask around in the spark forums. tks.